# Run script if on certain webpage AND leaving another certain webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've written a CSS code for a fade-in effect on the title of my website. It worked well, but I want to fade-in/out a certain part of the title depending on the page I'm LEAVING.

**Here's what I want:**

If I'm LEAVING the page titled "Biology" and GOING to the one titled "Biology → Zoology" I want to fade-in just the part " → Zoology" (and I've done it successfully), BUT if I'm STILL GOING "Biology → Zoology" and NOW LEAVING "Biology → Zoology → Vertebrates" I want to fade-out the part " → Vertebrates" and keep "Biology → Zoology".

**I think it'd be something like this:**

```
if ((window.location.pathname == 'x') && (Leaving_page == 'y')) {
            //code for fade-in/out here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the logic:

you need to use a script (eg php's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or anything else) to know the page where the user is coming from.

and you also need to write the different `css` animation effects using different class names (eg `.name-fade-out`, `.name-fade-in`)

Once you do that, use an `if` statement to do something like this in your "zoology" page:

```
if (prev_page == 'http://www.example.com/biology'){
    //print    Biology <span class=".name-fade-in"> → Zoology <span>
}
else if (prev_page == 'http://www.example.com/biology/zoology/vertebrates'){
    //print    Biology → Zoology <span class=".name-fade-out"> → Vertebrates <span>
}
else{
    //print    Biology → Zoology
}
```

and that's how you do it for all other pages